# Screw modifier of a curve that intersects the rotating axis produces weird faces and problematic normals

Tags: bezier-curves, retopology, screw-modifier

I have a curve on the XZ plane that intersects/crosses the Z axis (and its center of geometry)
[image]

I want to apply a screw modifier with only 4 steps using this curve, and the problem is that after that I have topology problems: I have intersecting faces, which is the expected since the curve intersects the rotating axis, but this generate a set of afterwards problems. See how we have weird faces at this point on the resulting mesh.

[image]

I think this is mainly because of the curves crossing it self the normals of the resulting faces are weird. For example in this image I moved one of the faces to understand the normals, and they same "face" have inner and outwards normals. I can't fix this by recalculating normals.

[image]

So at the end of the day if I want to use this object and add a modify solidifier and shadings everything works weird because of the normals problem.

So my question is, how can I revolve the original curve with the screw modifier without generating a mesh that has these topologies problems. By topology problems I mean normals that point two different directions on the same face.
I was thinking about splitting all faces and then merging them again, but I am not sure how to do this and if it actually would work.

Edit: accepted answer worked! See my answer for a follow up and a python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

If modifying the curve is an option, you can use the *Bisect* tool to split it along the axis, then reflect the right part on the left, keeping only points along the screw axis:

[image: Cut and reflect]

Comment: Worked! check also my answer to see a python implementation.

Answer (score 0):

[Accepted answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/315373/154713) by StefLAncien worked.
This is just a follow up to show that it worked and how it can be implemented in python.

Since I am implementing this on a script and I need to do it multiple times this is the code to mirror the curves at the crossing point.

```py
def interpolate_on_crossing(x, z, crossing_point=0):
    """
    Find the crossing points of the curve with the x=0 line. Add the crossing points to the curve.
    """
    new_x = []
    new_z = []
    for i in range(len(x) - 1):

        new_x.append(x[i])
        new_z.append(z[i])
        if x[i] <= crossing_point and x[i + 1] >= crossing_point:
            new_x.append(crossing_point)
            new_z.append(z[i] + (z[i + 1] - z[i]) / (x[i + 1] - x[i]) * (0 - x[i]))
        elif x[i] >= crossing_point and x[i + 1] <= crossing_point:
            new_x.append(crossing_point)
            new_z.append(z[i] + (z[i + 1] - z[i]) / (x[i + 1] - x[i]) * (0 - x[i]))

    new_x.append(x[-1])
    new_z.append(z[-1])
    return new_x, new_z


def fix_crossing_points(curves_zx):
    non_crossing_curves_xz = []
    for c in curves_zx:
        z, x = c
        new_x, new_z = interpolate_on_crossing(x, z)
        new_x = [x * -1 if x < 0 else x for x in new_x]
        non_crossing_curves_xz.append([new_x, new_z])

    return non_crossing_curves_xz


fixed_curves = fix_crossing_points(curves_zx)

plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
for c in curves_zx:
    plt.plot(c[1], c[0], "-o")


ax2 = plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
for c in fixed_curves:
    plt.plot(c[0], c[1], "-o")
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim())
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())
```

With a plot to show what it does (orange curve)

[image].

Finally, this is the mesh in blender after applying the script of a curve that was crossing the axis: all normals are facing the correct direction.

[image]